# JTable inside a JTree

Tags: java, jtable, jtree

I'm implementing a JTable inside of a JTree like [AT THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675009/showing-a-jtable-in-a-jtree-behaves-differently-with-different-look-and-feels). It works fine except that:

- The scrolling in the JTable doesn't work. There could be some interference because my JTreeis also in a scroll pane.
- The pane is always the same square size, I would like it to adjust to the width and height of the table (with a max height).
- I can't select cells in the JTable

How can I resolve the two above issues?

Comment: It is possible that you show us your code ?

Comment: I'm using the exact code from the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675009/showing-a-jtable-in-a-jtree-behaves-differently-with-different-look-and-feels) I cited above